# Problem with using non type parameter class template

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I am trying to create some type packing, value packing library for template meta programming usage. I have trouble with some template template non type parameter:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct type_identity {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename ...types>
struct type_pack {};

template <auto ...values>
struct value_pack {
  template <template <auto> typename meta_transformer>
  using transform_to_type = type_pack<typename meta_transformer<values>::type...>; //C2993 on MSVC
};

template <auto i>
struct type_map;

template <>
struct type_map<1> : type_identity<int> {};

template <>
struct type_map<2.0> : type_identity<double> {};

template <>
struct type_map<'c'> : type_identity<char> {};

int main() {
    using mapped_types = value_pack<1, 2.0, 'c'>::transform_to_type<type_map>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<mapped_types, type_pack<int, double, char>>, "Error!");
    return 0;
}
```

Here I am trying to create an alias template called `transform_to_type`, where I would be taking meta-functions that have type typedef, so than I can convert some `value_pack` to a `type_pack`.

The code above [works fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ey48h8hbk2vUAMSh) with GCC 12.2.0 with C++20(If float non type parameter is removed, it works in c++17 as well), didn't have chance to look at it in clang but on MSVC it doesn't compile and gives me a really weird error message:

`error C2993: 'auto': is not a valid type for non-type template parameter '__formal'`

Is this a bug of MSVC compiler? I am using Version 19.29.30151 and compiling my code with /std:c++20

Turning the problematic line to `using transform_to_type = type_pack<decltype(typename meta_transformer<values>::type())...>;` compiles in MSVC. This is a bit unexpected because the error message was kinda misleading for me and I was questioning whether auto is allowed in that context or not. I don't really want to add another wrapper on this just to deduce the type that's already a type there and gcc seems to accept it. How would I make this work on MSVC? Should I complain to MSVC for this or this is a nonstandard usage and it just happens to work on gcc?

Also I would be happy if there is any other way that can do the same thing I am trying to achieve but works with MSVC.

Comment: It compiles with MSVC 19.38.32919 so perhaps an upgrade would be good?

Comment: Your code [works fine with MSVC 19.31](https://godbolt.org/z/Whra56bWz).

Comment: I'll try to upgrade the compiler, thanks for the quick responses.

Comment: Apparently Visual Studio 2019's latest version supports up to my current version, so I need to install the Visual Studio 2022 to get cl version above 19.29. Most likely this is fixed there as the others pointed out that it compiles with 19.38 and 19.31.

Comment: @uxsu [Workaround for MSVC 19.30](https://godbolt.org/z/jf6Ynzre5).

Comment: @康桓瑋 Ohh I didn't know Godbolt has MSVC compilers as well, thanks a lot. I'll definitely upgrade cl to a more recent version.